# LaunchImage does not handle certain iPads correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, launchimage

I am using an images.xcassets for my app's LaunchImage, and certain types of iPad's are showing the iPhone image or the AppIcon image on launch instead of the designated iPad image.

[image: Ipad 5th Generation 10.3 simulator]

Here is a screenshot of my App Icons and Launch Images Settings

[image]

Below is the code for Contents.json of my xcassets file:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "subtype" : "736h",
      "filename" : "ios_launch 7 plus.png",
      "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "scale" : "3x"
    },
    {
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "subtype" : "667h",
      "filename" : "ios_launch 7@2x.png",
      "minimum-system-version" : "8.0",
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "filename" : "ios_launch se-1.png",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "idiom" : "iphone",
      "subtype" : "retina4",
      "filename" : "ios_launch se.png",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "ios_launch ipad.png",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "orientation" : "portrait",
      "idiom" : "ipad",
      "filename" : "ios_launch ipad pro.png",
      "extent" : "full-screen",
      "minimum-system-version" : "7.0",
      "scale" : "2x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

I am unsure why this is happening. This does not occur on iPad Air. There are very little docs that I have been able to find to help. Appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score -1):

Use Launch storyboard and set the respective image and align image aspect ratio from center.

Comment: I am unsure of how to use storyboard to set multiple images for different devices. Can you point me in the right direction?